# Insert values into mysql with foreign key constraints

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables as : **'spen_recipe' and 'spen_recipe_type'** as shown below

[image]

I want to insert the values into spen_recipe and spen_recipe_type simultaneously based on the pk and fk constraints.

Please suggest me the query.

This is what i have tried:

```
insert into spen_recipe
 (`user_id`,`recipe_name`,`recipe_title`,`recipe_type`,`cooking_time`,`preparation_time`,`serving_to`,`recipe_desc`,`recipe_photo`,`created_at`,`modified_at`,`published_at`)
values
('2','recipe2','title2',(select `recipe_type_id` from spen_recipe_type),'20','30','4','desc1','image1','2016-11-05 11:21:43','2016-11-05 11:22:43','2016-11-05 11:21:43');
```

But need suggestion on how to proceed after select `recipe_type_id` from spen_recipe_type, cause both the table has null values in the columns, both are empty.

Should spen_recipe_type or spen_recipe be first inserted?

Comment: You can't insert rows simultaneously. You have to insert the first row, determine what PK was generated for it, then insert the second row with the FK set to the PK you just got for the previous insert. If you need that to be treated as an atomic operation (both rows insert or neither row inserts) then you should wrap the operation in a transaction.  As for insert order, you should always insert into the table that doesn't have an FK constraint first. The table that has an FK constraint (dependant table in the terminology) can't have correct data inserted if it doesn't exist in the parent yet

Comment: pls explain with ex query

Comment: I'm happy to help but I'm not going to do the work for you.  You'd start with a call to begin the transaction (depends on what database API you're using) then `INSERT` your new recipe type,  then get the last insert ID on recipe type (again it depends on your database API but with PDO it would be http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php, `INSERT` your new recipie with the type ID set to the last insert ID you just retrieved, then finally commit the transaction (for example with http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)